# OpenSSL PHP RSA Encryption: Which library to use to decrypt on client side?

Tags: openssl, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have developed a desktop application (.NET 2.0) and it needs to get some information from a server running php/mysql. The provider at server end has decided to use encryption using openssl_private_encrypt method and has provided me a publickey.pem file. I am not good at php/mysql but i do know that it would not be any different if i were using asp .net.

My question is how do i decrypt private-enrypted data in a .NET 2.0 application. All my attempts to use the RSACrypoServiceProvider with the publickey have proven unsuccessful.

I stumbled upon ManagedOpenSSL library but that was no good either.

I am certain many at StackOverflow would have done similar stuff and it would be nice o know how they did it.

Appreciate all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i used to make it work!

```
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            string responseFromServerEnc = string.Empty;

            byte[] data = null;

            if (HttpStatusCode.OK == response.StatusCode)
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(0x10000);

                using (Stream responseStream =            request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
                    int bytes;
                    while ((bytes = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    }

                    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }

                response.Close();
            }


            const string pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n key from .pem file \n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
            PemReader pem = new PemReader(new StringReader(pubKey));
            RsaKeyParameters bcp = (RsaKeyParameters)pem.ReadObject();

            string responseFromServer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(data,bcp));
```

And responseFromServerEnc was the encrypted message and responseFromServer was correctly decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses XML formatted keys which OpenSSL doesn't support.  My recommendation would be to generate the key pair - or at least convert the existing one to XML - with [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks newbert. However, generating a keypair would mean that i ask the server admin to use the private key that i generate and i do not think they would entertain such requests.

I will post the answer below.

But, i think i managed to get it to work after a few hours of hit and trial. I used BouncyCastle and then with a bit of hit-and-trial managed to figure it out.